# Polygon Extent to Xmin, Ymin, Xmax, Ymax .csv

Tags: python, shapefile, csv

I have a piece of code that reads in a `.csv` file and outputs a shapefile. After processing and altering the shapefile. The shapefile contains multiple polygons. I need to turn it back into the `.csv`, but am unsure how to "go backwards". I was thinking that I could do it somehow with the raster's resolution and polygons extents, but just am kind of confused with the process. Ultimately, I want to convert the `.csv` into an `.xml`.

Any advice?

```
training_csv = gpd.read_file('D:/data/farmer.csv')
training_csv.drop(['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'geometry'], axis=1, inplace=True)

tif_file = 'D:/data/farmer/tif/0.tif'  # georeferenced TIFF
shp_path = 'D:/data/farmer/shape/'  # don't add extension

save_name = 0

# open georeferenced tif file
with rasterio.open(tif_file) as image:
    for i in training_csv.iterrows():
        xmin = float(i[1][3])
        ymin = float(i[1][2])
        xmax = float(i[1][1])
        ymax = float(i[1][0])

        # get vertices of the bounding box
        # geocoordinates from pixel coordinates
        p1 = image.xy(xmin, ymin)
        p2 = image.xy(xmax, ymin)
        p3 = image.xy(xmax, ymax)
        p4 = image.xy(xmin, ymax)
        print(p1)

        # save shapefile containing one bounding box shape
        w = shapefile.Writer(shp_path + str(save_name) + '.shp')
        w.field("name", "C")  # pyshp needs at least one field
        w.poly([[p1, p2, p3, p4]])  # generate bbox polygon
        w.record('bbox')
        w.close()

        # generate .PRJ file
        crs_wkt = image.crs.to_wkt()
        prj = open(shp_path + str(save_name) + '.prj', "w")
        prj.write(crs_wkt)
        prj.close()

        save_name = save_name + 1
```

**Original CSV**

[image]

Comment: Each row in the `csv` contains the extent of one polygon. So in this picture I would have 20 polygons for `0.tif`. For another `tif` file I could have 3 polygons. So on and so forth. Based on the `tifs` properties such as projection, the xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax coordinates are being converted into geocoordinates. So that I can properly view them in QGIS.

Comment: In QGIS I create a fishnet (lets say of 100x100ft). For simplicity sake lets say the csv above gets clipped into 5 polygons that contain 4 polygons each (20 polygons total). I need to take each of the polygons and turn their geo-extent-coordinates back into xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax based on a predetermined (0,0). Lets say the bottom left corner of the polygon that holds the smaller ones.

Comment: So from the csv above, convert each row to geo-referenced `shp`. Clip into smaller sections. Convert back to positions based on a determined (0,0) point.

Comment: Does that help?

Answer (score 3):

I found something similar to convert shapefiles to CSV on [deepforest](https://github.com/weecology/DeepForest/blob/main/deepforest/utilities.py). DeepForest is a python package for training and predicting individual tree crowns from airborne RGB imagery.
The following code converts the shapefile to csv.

```
import os
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import rasterio
import shapely
def shapefile_to_annotations(shapefile, rgb):
    """
    Args:
        shapefile: Path to a shapefile on disk. If a label column is present, it will be used, else all labels are assumed to be "Tree"
        rgb: Path to the RGB image on disk
    Returns:
        results: a pandas dataframe
    """
    # Read shapefile
    gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile)

    # get coordinates
    df = gdf.geometry.bounds

    # raster bounds
    with rasterio.open(rgb) as src:
        left, bottom, right, top = src.bounds
        resolution = src.res[0]

    # Transform project coordinates to image coordinates
    df["tile_xmin"] = (df.minx - left) / resolution
    df["tile_xmin"] = df["tile_xmin"].astype(int)

    df["tile_xmax"] = (df.maxx - left) / resolution
    df["tile_xmax"] = df["tile_xmax"].astype(int)

    # UTM is given from the top, but origin of an image is top left

    df["tile_ymax"] = (top - df.miny) / resolution
    df["tile_ymax"] = df["tile_ymax"].astype(int)

    df["tile_ymin"] = (top - df.maxy) / resolution
    df["tile_ymin"] = df["tile_ymin"].astype(int)

    # Add labels is they exist
    if "label" in gdf.columns:
        df["label"] = gdf["label"]
    else:
        df["label"] = "Tree"

    # add filename
    df["image_path"] = os.path.basename(rgb)

    # select columns
    result = df[[
        "image_path", "tile_xmin", "tile_ymin", "tile_xmax", "tile_ymax", "label"
    ]]
    result = result.rename(columns={
        "tile_xmin": "xmin",
        "tile_ymin": "ymin",
        "tile_xmax": "xmax",
        "tile_ymax": "ymax"
    })

    # ensure no zero area polygons due to rounding to pixel size
    result = result[~(result.xmin == result.xmax)]
    result = result[~(result.ymin == result.ymax)]

    return result

results=shapefile_to_annotations(shapefile='pathtoshapfile.shp', rgb='path_to_tif.tif')

results.to_csv('path_to_save_csv')
```

Comment: Thanks for posting, I'll need to take some time to figure out why I needed this again. I'll get back to you!